# Update youtube-dl on mac OS X

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-elcapitan, youtube-dl

I tried to update latest release on youtube-dl but I can't update and while I tried  got the error like
 **"It looks like you installed youtube-dl with a package manager, pip, setup.py or a tarball. Please use that to update."**

Comment: How did you try to update it?

Comment: @mipadi I followed  youtube-dl  documentation

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try:

```
youtube-dl -U
```

If you used pip to install youtube-dl in the first place then, use:

```
pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

If that doesn't work, you can always reinstall it using homebrew:

```
brew install youtube-dl
```

Answer (score 10):

To install use: 
`brew install youtube-dl`

To upgrade use: 
`brew upgrade youtube-dl`